# Greenplum Django migrate distribution key error

Tags: django, web-applications, greenplum

I am currently working on a Greenplum project. Part of this project is creating a simple webapp for the visualization and statistics of data.

When I tried integrating Greenplum with Django it failed, giving me the following error:

> `python manage.py migrate` : UNIQUE index must contain all columns in the 
>   distribution key of relation `django_content_type`.

It appears that Django cannot create some of its tables, specifically `django_content_type`. When the user doesn't specify a distribution key for Greenplum, the primary key is chosen and in the case of the `django_content table`, column `id` was chosen by default as the distribution key.

Later on, Django tried to define `django_content_type_app_label`as a UNIQUE value. The distribution key then was automatically redefined to match the unique field. However, the primary key (`id`) is not a subset of the distribution key, and this is one of the requirements of Greenplum.

Is there a workaround to this migration issue to integrate Django with Greenplum? I have searched but not found anything helpful. Unfortunately, **use of Greenplum is mandatory**, so I cannot use another database.

Alternatively, what framework could be used instead of Django? I know R applications are supported but this is also unfortunately not an option for this project.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried Apache Zeppelin?

Comment: No,haven't tried it and haven't used it before. I just took a look and it seems to be an interesting alternative. However, I need to do some more reading before I decide whether this fully fits the requirements of my project. If you can think of any other options, please do let me know.

Comment: You could try updating the Django script to remove the additional indexes.